# How to visualize a polyhedron with faces consisting of different number of vertices?

Tags: sagemath

For each face of a polyhedron, I have a list of all vertices being a part of said face.

Example data for a polyhedron consisting of $13$ vertices and $9$ faces, where vertices are numbered from $0$:

```
0 1 2
0 2 3 7 5 6 4
0 4 8 1
1 8 9 11 10 3 2
3 10 7
4 6 12 9 8
5 7 10 11 12
5 12 6
9 12 11
```

How can I visualize this polyhedron in $3D$?

Comment: Do you also have the vertex coordinates?